Unity Profiler : Texture.AwakeFromLoad CPU spike
I have CPU spike when I load any scene, and this is what I have in the profilter:


It is a 2D game and the scenes are not very complicated. There are only a few sprites and objects (I used sprite sheets by the way), so I think this is not normal.
Any idea how to reduce this?
Additionally, what does "Texture.AwakeFromLoad" mean? The Unity documentation on "Asynchronous Texture Upload" hasn't been very helpful.
Thanks in advance for your help!
I tried SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync, not sure if it is related to the issue, I just wanted to give it a shot, and it didn't work.

How large are your textures?

It is 100 MB for the entire game. By the way, something funny happened: when I closed and reopened Unity, the profiler values changed (I don't know how; I literally changed nothing). Now, I have a CPU spike on WaitForAsyncOperationToComplete.
